# How to solve equal function in ocaml?

Tags: function, sorting, functional-programming, ocaml

Write a function equals: ’a list -> ’a list -> bool
equals l1 l2 returns true if the two lists l1 and l2 are equal (i.e. if they contain
the same elements at the same positions), and false otherwise. The constraint is that you
cannot use l1 = l2 directly, so you are asked to entirely redefine
equality between two lists.

Mine version have errors:

```
let rec equals l1 l2 =
  match l1, l2 with
    [], [] -> true
  | (_, []) -> false
  | ([], _) -> false
  | (x1::r1), (x2::r2) ->
      if x1 = x2 then equals (x1::r1) (x2::r2) 
      else false;;
```

(Note: the function must not contain predefined functions )

Comment: What are the errors? This isn't a homework generation service.

Comment: # equals  [5; 2; 4; 7; 3] [5; 2; 4; 7; 3];;
Error: Unbound value equals
*I am conscious that it isn't a homework solver plateform but I had no choice, I have been struggling to write the function for long time.

Comment: This error means that you have not defined the `equals` function.

Comment: As pointed out by @octachron, `equals (x1::r1) (x2::r2)` in your function will never terminate. Follow the lead from the answer.

Comment: Suggestion: use a conditional guard. `| (x1::_), (x2::_) when x1 <> x2 -> false | ...`. You now know in the next pattern that the first elements are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you asked how to fix your code:

```
let rec equals l1 l2 =
  match l1, l2 with
    [], [] -> true
  | (_, []) -> false
  | ([], _) -> false
  | (x1::r1), (x2::r2) ->
      if x1 = x2 then equals (x1::r1) (x2::r2) 
      else false;;
```

should be changed to

```
let rec equals l1 l2 =
  match l1, l2 with
    [], [] -> true
  | (_, []) -> false
  | ([], _) -> false
  | (x1::r1), (x2::r2) ->
      if x1 = x2 then equals r1 r2 
      else false;;
```

Why would you pass the whole list `x1::r1` **again** as an argument for `equals` instead of the **rest** of the list? Otherwise, your function will never terminate for lists longer than 1, as the size does not get smaller.

Answer (score 2):

A recursive function `f` is guaranteed to terminate if the body of its definition

```
let rec f x = ... (* ← body *)
```

only contains recursive calls `f y` for values of `y` that are "smaller" than the original argument `x` of the function (where smaller means x < y for well-founded relation `<`).

Once a recursive function compiles without warning about a non-exhaustive pattern matching, the next step should be to check this criteria.